# How far can I downsample two sets A and B to compute the Jaccard Index of A and B?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence

Let be $A$ and $B$ two sets such that $|A|=N_A$ and $|B|=N_B$.
Let be $(A_n)_{1\leq n \leq N_A}$ a sequence of sets such that $A_n \subset A$, $|A_n|=n$. Analogously, consider the sequence $(B_n)_{1\leq n\leq N_B}$.

Denoting $J$ the Jaccard Index,
$J(E,F) = 2 \frac{|E \cap F|}{|E| + |F|}$,
how to choose $r$ and $s$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|J(A_r, B_s) - J(A, B)| \leq \varepsilon) > 1 - \eta$ ?

Note that, $N_A \gg 1$ and $N_B \gg 1$, I don't know if it may help. But that's the case I am considering.

Moreover, $J(A,B)$ is known. I could compute $J(A_r, B_s)$ as well, but the value of this quantity depends on how $A_r$ and $B_s$ are defined. I would assume that $A_r$ and $B_s$ are built by randomly downsampling $A$ and $B$ (without replacement), and I hope to be able to estimate the probability numerically with some Monte-Carlo simulations, because I don't think we can come up with an analytic estimation.

Does it make sense ? Can you help me to better formulate this probabilistic problem ? Feel free to suggest anything to clarify this question.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing since you only have finite sequences and so convergence is either trivial or undefined depending on the interpretation.

Comment: Yeah.. I see. Basically, my goal is to see how far I can downsample $A$ and $B$ but still have a negligble error.

Comment: Then maybe you are looking for a probabilistic formulation? Given a random subset of A of size m, and random subset of B of size n, what is the probability that the Jaccard index differs from the actual one by p percent?

Comment: Or an optimization formulation - given subset sizes m and n, what is the lowest and highest possible Jacard index of the original sets?

Comment: I would go for the probabilistic formulation. It better fits my needs.

Comment: You can get $\gg$ using `\gg`.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify it. People shouldn't have to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: @joriki done :) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you want to down-sample $A$ and $B$ while still having negligible error. I assume you want to know how to compare $J(A,B)$ and $J(A_p, B_q)$ compare for the same.

To this I think you need to define a way new elements get selected in the set, otherwise you can not guarantee what level of down-sampling might end in reasonably less error. That is in $A_i = A_{i-1} \cup \{a_i\} $ where $a_i ∈ A - A_{i-1}$ you need to tell how the $a_i$ is being selected.

**This is my reasoning:**

There are 2 cases:

1. $|A \cap B| = 0$

Well in this case both $J(A,B)$ and $J(A_p, B_q)$ will always be $0$. So, no problem of convergence here, I suppose.

2. $|A \cap B| \neq 0$

Well, now lets consider how $a_i$ might be selected, which in turn has 4 ways:

[image: 4 ways]

In $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ cases the $a_i$ will start in one region ($A-B$ in $1^{st}$ case) exhaust it completely then move to other region ($A \cap B$ in $1^{st}$ case).

In $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ case the $a_i$ will start in one region then in any fashion alternate between the regions ($A-B$ or $A \cap B$).

Similiar story $b_i$ on $B_q$ side.

If you would give some information on how the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are chosen I think we can make build a better understanding of how much down-sampling of $A$ and $B$ we can do.

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the context of your question and comments, I assume the following.

- The sizes $|A|$ and $|B|$ are known.
- It is hard to compute the size $|A \cap B|$ (and therefore it is also hard to compute $|A \cup B|$.
- For any particular element $a \in A$, it is easy to decide if $a \in B$. In practice, maybe $B$ is represented by a hash set or Bloom filter with negligible probability of error.
- It is easy to sample random elements of $A$.

Now note that when $|A|$ is large, the difference between sampling with and without replacement becomes negligible. So for simplicity, we can use sampling with replacement. Also note that estimating $|A \cap B|$ is the same difficulty as estimating $J(A, B)$, since they are proportional by they known constant $\frac{2}{|A| + |B|}$. So it it suffices to produce a good estimate of $|A \cap B|$.

Let $X_i$ with $i \in 1 \ldots n$ be random samples from $A$, sampled with replacement so that $X_i$ are iid. Consider the estimator $Y_n := \frac{|A|}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n  1[X_i \in B]$. We have $E[Y_n] = |A \cap B|$.

For any $i$ we have $1[X_i \in B]$ is distributed Bernoulli($p = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|A |})$. By a standard result in statistics (Binomial distribution converges very quickly to Gaussian), for $n$ large, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1[X_i \in B]$ is approximately distributed as a normal distribution $N(p, \frac{p(1-p)}{\sqrt n})$. Hence $Y_n$ is approximately distributed as $N(|A| p, \frac{|A|^2 p(1-p)}{\sqrt n}) = N(|A\cap B|, \frac{|A \cap B| | A \cap B^c|}{\sqrt n}) $.

So we have $P(|Y_n - |A\cap B|| \ge \epsilon) \approx 2 (1 - \Phi(\frac{\epsilon \sqrt n}{|A \cap B| |A \cup B^c|})) $.

By assumption, it's hard to compute $|A \cap B|$ that appears on the right hand side. Instead, we can do a worst case analysis by choosing $B$ to maximize the right hand side.

$\text{argmax}_{B} 2 (1 - \Phi(\frac{\epsilon \sqrt n}{|A \cap B| |A \cup B^c|})) =  \text{argmin}_B \Phi(\frac{\epsilon \sqrt n}{|A \cap B| |A \cup B^c|})$
$= \text{argmin}_B \frac{\epsilon \sqrt n}{|A \cap B| |A \cup B^c|}$
$= \text{argmax}_B |A \cap B| |A \cup B^c|$
$= \text{argmax}_B |A \cap B| (|A| - |A \cap B|)$

And so the maximizing choice is $B'$, such that $|A \cap B'| = |A|/2$.

Then $P(|Y_n - |A\cap B|| \ge \epsilon) \lessapprox 2 (1 - \Phi(\frac{4\epsilon \sqrt n}{|A|^2}))$.

This gives the following algorithm for choosing $n$.

1. Choose the desired tolerance $\epsilon$.
2. Choose $\eta$, the acceptable probability of an out of tolerance estimator.
3. Start at $n=1$ and increment $n$ until $ 2 (1 - \Phi(\frac{4\epsilon \sqrt n}{|A|^2})) < \eta$.

Your final $n$ is then a sample size such that $P(|Y_n - |A\cap B|| \ge \epsilon) < \eta$.

**Remarks**
Instead of sampling from $A$, you could also sample from $B$, in which case you would use the condition $2 (1 - \Phi(\frac{4\epsilon \sqrt n}{|B|^2})) < \eta$ in the last step. This is advantageous if $|B| < |A|$.

Also the last step (3) is a linear search. This is obviously bad. You can replace it with a binary search since the bound is monotonic in $n$. Or you could use an analytic approximation as mentioned [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds/) in John D. Cook's blog.

Comment: I think there is a typo because I found that $Y_n \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(|A \cap B|, \frac{1}{n}|A \cap B||A \cap B^c|)$.

Comment: But the reasoning looks good to me. Let me check it and I will validate your answer :)